# Android asynchronous event handling (callbacks and eventbus)

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, bluetooth, callback

I am currently developing an Android application with Bluetooth Low Energy capabilities. Android BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) method calls are mostly (if not all) asynchronous in nature. I have encapsulated this BLE handling functionality into a `Service` and trying to decouple other parts of the app from "specific implementation/interface of Android BLE Library." Because Android Bluetooth API is asynchronous, I am trying to "pass on" the Android BLE callbacks to the calling modules.

My example use case is as Below.

`externalModuleInstance.getSomeProperty()` would call `bleService.readCharacteristic(somePropertyId)` and when some asynchronous operation is done in Android BLE stack, bleService would get notified via Android BLE API's callback of the result. **How should I pass this result back to *externalModuleInstance*?**

I came up with three options: callbacks, listeners, and EventBus(by greenrobot).

1. **Listeners**: I would define `BleServiceInterface` and define some `onSomeEvent()` methods and implement this interface in `ExternalModule`. Then I would register this `ExternalModule` instance as `BleService`'s listener. This seems good that interface declaration seems explicit and clear.
2. **EventBus**: I just love this module for it's simplicity and elegance, but I don't think this is the right use case for an event bus (lower case intended) because `ExternalModule` is not interested in a *particular class/type of event* but rather to results of `BleService`.
3. **Callbacks**: The Downside seems to be that I have to define each class for each type of results. I could use generics but eventually I would have to supply the class of event (sort of C struct-looking) so I think it's the same thing. Also code would look a little bit more nested and complicated if I decide to use instantiate callback classes on the fly and pass into method parameters. *However*, I feel like callbacks are the way to go in this case because it seems like the right mechanism for *receiving asynchronous call results* as it is scoped per-method.

**I am really curious about what others think about this issue and what to use in this situation, and maybe asynchronous event handling in general.** Please feel free to correct and educate me!